# Angular 6: You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule

Tags: angular

Before minusing, please note that no other issues reported helped me. Looked through the whole stackoverflow regarding this issue.

This is in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LalaComponent } from './lala/lala.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiModule } from 'atlas-client';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LalaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ApiModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is in `lala.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lala',
  templateUrl: './lala.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lala.component.css']
})
export class LalaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('test');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "lala-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Error: You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule!  See
>   also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575
>
> ```
> at new ApiModule (atlas-client.js:216)
> at _createClass (core.js:9264)
> at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:9234)
> at initNgModule (core.js:9170)
> at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:9899)
> at createNgModuleRef (core.js:9888)
> at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:11719)
> at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create
> ```
>
> (core.js:12421)
>       at core.js:4720
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)

Please note, that the issue still there when I remove `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` line with respective import.

Comment: can you show the class for the `AppModule`?

Comment: Please show the whole content of `app.module.ts`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, done

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this behaviour in a StackBlitz or similar?

Comment: can you add `package.json`? Also are you using `atlas-client.js`?

Comment: @user184994, nope, it would require applying custom dependency (atlas-client).

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal, done. Yes, `atlas-client` is a custom dependency I added.

Comment: @AmazingDayToday there is problem with `atlas-client` module, are you sure it's supporting `Angular 6` ?

Comment: According to the discussion in the [issue 20575](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575), the error could be caused by another module that imports `HttpClientModule`. Check if it is imported only in `AppModule`.

Comment: @AmazingDayToday I am facing the exactly same problem with swagger-codegen. Do you have any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in angular-cli when the swagger-codegen package is either linked using  `npm link` or installed directly using: `npm install PATH_TO_GENERATED_PACKAGE/dist --save` (see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284).

The issue seems to be with `ng serve` only, not with `ng build --prod --base-href=...`, but I did not test an 'ng build' yet.

The "*You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule!*" message is not valid, but an error is thrown anyhow.

An (ugly) workaround described in this ticket is to generate the code using swagger-codegen-cli (or openapi-generator-cli), search for, and comment out the error message:

```
// if (!http) {
//     throw new Error('You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule! \n' +
//     'See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575');
// }
```

Next: run `npm install && npm run build` and install the package in the consuming project.

A cleaner solution would be to use a (private) npm registry.

---

**UPDATE 14/7/2018**

Further investigation showed that the [workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284) described above does not solve all problems.
Instead, I am now using a private npm registry [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) and have no issues anymore.

-Arjen

Comment: adding "preserveSymlinks": true under  "architect"/"build"/ "options" in angular.json also  solves the issue when the package is linked with npm link

            ,